# Python allowing @ in alphanumeric regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I only want to allow alphanumeric & a few characters (`+`, `-`, `_`, whitespace) in my string. But python seems to allow `@` and `.` (dot) along with these. How do I exclude `@`?

```
import re

def isInvalid(name):
    is_valid_char = bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9+-_\s]+$', name))
    if not is_valid_char:
        print('Name has invalid characters')
    else:
        print('Name is valid')
        
isInvalid('abc @')
```

This outputs 'Name is valid', how do I exclude `@`? Have tried to search this, but couldn't find any use case related to `@`. You can try this snippet here - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Try putting your dash at the end: `[a-zA-Z0-9+_\s-]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the regex you've used in your code, I believe you're trying to allow all alphanumeric characters and the characters `+`, `-`, `_` and empty spaces in your string. In that case, the problem here is that you're not escaping the characters `+` and `-`. These characters are special characters in a regular expression and need to be escaped. (what characters need to be escaped depends on what flavor of regex you're working with, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316)).

Modifying your code as follows produces expected results:

```py
import re

def isInvalid(name):
    is_valid_char = bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9\+\-_\s]+$', name))
    if not is_valid_char:
        print('Name has invalid characters')
    else:
        print('Name is valid')
        
isInvalid('abc @')  # prints "Name has valid characters"
```

You can run it online [here](https://trinket.io/python3/e709e8780a)

Answer (score 3):

This part `+-_` of your regex matches in range of index 43 and 95. You need to use a `\` to remove the meaning of the `-`

Your RegEx should look like this: `[a-zA-Z0-9+\-_\s]+$`